# How can I get data from input fields that are on master page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, input, master-pages, gettext

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 2 technology for developing my web site. I have two input fields in my master page (username and password) and one submit button.
How can I get data from those input fields?
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what i was looking for. Thank you for your answers.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account", FormMethod.Post))  {  %>

  <%= Html.LabelFor(d => d.UserName)%>:
  <%= Html.EditorFor(d => d.UserName)%>

  <%= Html.LabelFor(d => d.Password)%>:
  <%= Html.Password("Password")%>

  <input type="submit" value="Login" />

  <%= Html.ValidationSummary() %>

<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably start at [this page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3)

When the form is submitted, it should direct to a server-side page that will process the data.

Check out [Read Post Data submitted to ASP.Net Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564289/read-post-data-submitted-to-asp-net-form) for some details on reading the data with that server side page.

Answer (score 0):

MasterPage:

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtUsername" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Content Code Behind:

```
string username = ((TextBox)Master.FindControl("txtUsername")).Text;
```