# i need to pass the parameter from jquery to my codebehind

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

i tried for creating a bookmark for my asp.net code the aspx page is written in jquery,so i need to pass the parameter from jquery to the codebehind of the .aspx page.Can anyone help me out in passing the parameter to codebehind?

Comment: Please elaborate, because your question does not provide enough information. You could use Ajax or post back a form to the server, but maybe you don't really need to do this. Keep in mind that JavaScript runs in the browser and the code in the code-behind file runs on the server.

Answer (score 1):

The use of a hidden field will be your solution :

In javascript :

```
function SetValue()
{
    $('#<%=Hidden1.ClientID%>').val() = "testing !!!!!";
}
```

And in html you need this :

```
<input id="Hidden1" runat="server" type="hidden" value="" />
```

or this :

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="Hidden1" runat="server" Value="" />
```

And then because you hiddenfield is runat server you can access it in the code behind at the next post back.

If you don't want to do a postback you may need to use a webMethod

Comment: At the runtime ID value may be change, therefore I think it will be safer to use class instead of id

Comment: It's true or use this <%=Hidden1.ClientID%>

Comment: Input type values are passed as a part of Request.Form NameValueCollection. You can use the "name" property of the hidden input type for accessing the value from this collection. Check out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564289/read-post-data-submitted-to-asp-net-form

Answer (score 0):

In addition on using Hidden field, I always avoid using spaghetti code. You can do this in jQuery. using the $ selector, you will always get the correct ID of a server control.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="Hidden1" runat="server" Value="" />
<style type="text/javascript">
    function SetValue()
    {
        $("input[id$='Hidden1']").val("Some Value");
    }
</style>
```