# The name 'txtBxSearch' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, input

I have a code here that consist of input box and a text area, but when I'm about to call the input box which name is txtBxSearch. An error occurred, It says "The name 'txtBxSearch' does not exist in the current context"

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

<div style="padding-top:10px; padding-left:40px;"> <span class="fields">To:</span><br />
   <input type="text" id="txtBxSearch" name="txtBxSearch" class="border fields" 
    style="width:891px;" onclick="return txtBxSearch_onclick()" />
```

```
<div style="padding-top:10px; padding-left:40px;"><span class="fields">Text Message:</span><br />
<textarea id="TextArea1" onkeyup="textCounter(this,'counter',160);"  cols="20" rows="2" class="fields border" style="height:150px; width:95%;"></textarea>
```

```
</asp:Content>
```

My code behind in C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class SMS : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
private string groupKeyword;
private string message;
private int priorityLevel;
private bool isDiagnosticCommand;
private bool concatenate;
private object confirmationDate;


protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {

        groupKeyword = txtBxSearch.value;
        message = TextArea1.Value;
        priorityLevel = 253;
        //confirmationDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        isDiagnosticCommand = false;
        concatenate = false;


}
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564289/read-post-data-submitted-to-asp-net-form

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your control `txtbxSearch` is an HTML control, its not an ASP.Net control. That is why you can't access it in your code behind.

Specify `runat="server"` attribute with your textbox, and you should be able to access it in code behind.

You can also try in code behind:

```
string value = Request.Form["txtbxSearch"];
```

if you don't want to use `runat="server"` with the input control.

Comment: Is there any other way to access my control in html in asp?

Comment: but when I use runat="server" it says : "
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText' to 'string'"

Comment: @ChristineS, I am not sure how you are trying to access that control in code behind. It will not be accessible as a normal ASP.Net TextBox. Try `string value = Request.Form["txtbxSearch"];` to get the value

Comment: and now there is a new error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Request.get'"

Comment: @ChristineS, I just test it with your code and it seems to be working. You may place your C# code behind code where you are accessing it in your question, and I would be able to see if there is something else going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

your code needs to be:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

<div style="padding-top:10px; padding-left:40px;"> <span class="fields">To:</span><br />
   <input type="text" id="txtBxSearch" name="txtBxSearch" class="border fields" 
    style="width:891px;" onclick="return txtBxSearch_onclick()" runat="server" />
<div style="padding-top:10px; padding-left:40px;"><span class="fields">Text Message:</span><br />
<textarea id="TextArea1" onkeyup="textCounter(this,'counter',160);"  cols="20" rows="2" class="fields border" style="height:150px; width:95%;"></textarea>
</asp:Content>
```

Note the runat=server in the txtBxSearch

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access it you just need a runat="server" attribute

```
<div style="padding-top:10px; padding-left:40px;"> <span class="fields">To:</span><br />
       <input type="text" id="txtBxSearch" name="txtBxSearch" class="border fields" 
        style="width:891px;" onclick="return txtBxSearch_onclick()" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Snap Shot from visual studio]

In the visual studio change the value of GenerateMember to True . Then you can the get the text field name. It worked for me.