# Adding User controls dynamically

Tags: asp.net, .net, user-controls, updatepanel

I am trying to add user controls once the page is loaded.In the page depending on the selection (dropdown or checkbox) the respective user control will be added.I know that if we need to add user controls I need to add them in the Page_InIt method.but I will know which user control to add only when the page is completely loaded and the user has made a selection.
The page has Update panel so there will be many Async postback's so I also need to look at how to persist the user-control once it is added to the page.

Any help will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can get user selection using the

`Request.Form["YourControlID"]`.

Check this link to know about getting postback data from forms

[Read Post Data submitted to ASP.Net Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564289/read-post-data-submitted-to-asp-net-form)

Also read this post about using dynamic controls in ASP.NET. It very helpfull.

[TRULY UNDERSTANDING DYNAMIC CONTROLS](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/25/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-1_2900_.aspx)