# Get POST values from an Ajax request for ASP.Net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, post

I'm pulling my hair out. I can't get this simple thing to work. I can't get the values from POST? What's the trick to reading POST values within aspx pages.

Here is the html page.

```
                <html>
                <head>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <form id="frm_post" action="default.aspx" method="POST">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Name 2:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="txtName2″" name="name2″" value="Jack" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Address 2:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="txtAddr2″" name="addr2″" value="Oz" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="Send Using Post" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    </form>
                </body>
                </html>
```

Here is my aspx pge

```
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {


                if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
                {
                    string text = Request.Form["name2"];
                    Response.Output.WriteLine(text);
                }

            }
```

Comment: so action of your HTML page is set to aspx page with method set to POST? did you try...Response.write(text)? try commenting out the IF statement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564289/read-post-data-submitted-to-asp-net-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an extra double quote character on your field `ID` and `name` values.

```
<td>
    <input type="text" id="txtName2″" name="name2″" value="Jack" />
</td>
```

Should be

```
<td>
    <input type="text" id="txtName2" name="name2" value="Jack" />
</td>
```

The same happens to your `txtAddr2` field. As the saying goes, 'The Devil is in the detail'.

Comment: That looks like it was the problem. I copied the code form a website and seams like something got corrupt because the double quotes kept coming back after saving the file.

Answer (score 0):

something like this...

```
NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;
string userName, password;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["txtUserName"]))
{
  userName = nvc["txtUserName"];
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["txtPassword"]))
{
  password = nvc["txtPassword"];
}
```